# Program bypasses while loop with multiple conditions (java)

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I have this really simple code:

```
public class ArrayIO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);    
        System.out.println("Enter a number from 50 to 150: ");
        int elements = sc.nextInt();

        while(elements<50 && elements>150) {
            System.out.println("Less than 50 or more than 150");
            elements = sc.nextInt();
        }
            sc.close();

            ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i=1; i<=elements; i++) {
                integers.add(i);
            }

            integers.toArray();

            System.out.printf("Array size is %d\n", integers.size());

    }

}
```

but my program bypasses the while loop completely when it has more than one condition. It works just fine with only one condition. I feel like I'm doing some really stupid mistake, but I just can't quite get it for almost an hour already.

Comment: So... how can elements be less than 50 and greater than 150 at the same time? I think you mean "or", `||` (Two pipes)

Comment: based on `System.out.println("Enter a number from 50 to 150: ");` you may want : `while( elements >= 50 && elements <= 150 )`

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider wow, it actually worked. Didn't think I made that stupid of a mistake, quite embarrassing, really. However, I believe I've tried it when I was using if-else statement instead of while loop and it didn't work. It works just fine now, though. Thanks!

Comment: @svasa No, since I want my array size to be >=50 and <=150, and this while loop cuts off every number lower than 50 and higher that 150

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `&&` to `||` if you want **OR**:

```
while(elements<50 || elements>150) {
    System.out.println("Less than 50 or more than 150");
...
```